# React Native Text Input Insert and Update

Tags: react-native

I have a screen it has text input's. I am trying to insert the `TextInput` value into the database and retrieve the data from database and display on the `TextInput`without any problem. But the problem is to edit the data on the `TextInput`. I try to edit the `TextInput`value the text cannot be changed.

```
if (this.state.mode == 'edit') {
    customer.updateCustomer(JSON.stringify(customerregVOObj)); 
} else {
    customerregVOObj._id = 'abc';
    customer.createCustomer(customerregVOObj); 
} 
updateCustomer = () => {
    customerregVOObj.shopName = this.state.shopName; 
}

<TextInput 
  underlineColorAndroid='transparent' style={styles.input}
  returnKeyType={"next"} autoFocus={true} placeholder="Shop Name"
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ shopName: text })}
  value={this.state.shopDetail.shopName} 
/>



this.state.mode == 'new' ? <Button onPress={this.updateCustomer} title="Submit" /> :
  <Button onPress={this.updateCustomer} title="Update" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong state in **value**. Kindly replace below code:

```
<TextInput 
  underlineColorAndroid='transparent' style={styles.input}
  returnKeyType={"next"} autoFocus={true} placeholder="Shop Name"
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ shopName: text })}
  value={this.state.shopName} 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your Response Nirmalsinh .Actually In componentDidMount() i call the getCustomerById() and assign the response value to shopDetail.So i think this is not a problem(value={this.state.shopDetail.shopName} ).

Comment: Can you please double check in getCustomeById() function, what is the value you will get?

Comment: I am getting response like {"shopName":"value1","_id":"1","_rev":"1b8675c89a"}

Comment: Can you share me how you stored this reponse in shopDetail object?

Comment: can you give your mail id i will send my full code to you

Comment: nirmit2507@gmail.com